# lxc with apparmor - where should be defined profiles

Tags: lxc, apparmor, debian-buster

I created `/root/example.sh` from [here](https://medium.com/information-and-technology/so-what-is-apparmor-64d7ae211ed) at the host, and with aa-genprof denied it.

```
# ./example.sh
This is an apparmor example.
./example.sh: line 5: /usr/bin/touch: Permission denied
File created
./example.sh: line 8: /bin/rm: Permission denied
File deleted
```

great - it works!

But if i copy it into containers (at the same `/root` folder)
it works normal (without any restrictions).

First think is to install apparmor at container, but wait!!! some of processes inside containers logs into host syslog (postdrop is denied to access dynamicmaps.cd.d - and this postdrop is running in container!).

So somehow I have to add example.sh into host apparmor.d, and it should also affect all containers... But how?